# Services as products in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question to ask, basically i want some consultation. I am writing a WordPress plugin for a client. **The goal of this plugin is to give the admin ability to sell its beauty services**.

I create a custom post type for order and its fine.

BUT now I am confused how I should maintain services as services are my product as well.

Each service belongs to a category as well as some addon's.

Like

```
Facial -- Category
-- Facial No.1 --- service
-- -- extra facial on demand --- addon
```

Shall i create a custom post type and handle as custom post type. or shall i create a taxonomy to handle the behavior

Comment: You should use an eCommerce plugin like woocommerce or prestashop to run on Wordpress. So you don’t need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: i know that, but things are quite different in my scenario

Comment: There are plenty of plugins you can use or plugins you can write to enhance the baseline. Sure they cover to sell services instead of products